# How to translate "infusion"? (The potentially intravenous kind, not herbal tea.)

Tags: single-word-requests

How to translate "infusion", i.e. a medical treatment in which liquid substances are delivered through a hollow needle directly into the body.

(E.g. [interstitial / subcutaneous infusion a.k.a. Hypodermoclysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypodermoclysis) or [intravenous infusion a.k.a. "drip"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravenous_therapy).)

(The [German word "Infusion"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infusion) is less ambiguous than the English one.)

Comment: [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q640448) has "intravejna terapio" as Esperanto name of the treatment, but is there a term that can be used independently of whether it's done as a therapy or not?

Comment: Context / Motivation: [This comment of mine](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/27454406#32507404) in the Duolingo forum.

Comment: Also there is a difference between intravenous infusion (like a drip) and an intravenous injection (infusion is usually diluted in a carrier and much more diluted while an injection is a direct and fairly quick delivery). And both would count as "intravejna terapio".

Comment: @ShaynePower Yeah, I think I'm really looking for the meaning captured by the German word "Infusion" which neither includes the meaning of "Spritze"/"Injektion" (e.g. a flue shot) nor that of "Aufguss"/"Kräutertee" (herbal tea and similar hot-water extractions).

Answer (score 1):

How about "gutado" as in "intravejna gutado?". That would mean we could also use "subhaŭta gutado".  Ŝi ricevas salon per intravejna gutado.

Comment: Is that based on more than the similarity/relation between the English words "drip" and "drop"? Would it be understood (with the intended meaning) by non-English-speaking Esperantists?

Comment: It's an educated guess. And I google-translated a non-English wiki article about it into Esperanto and that's the sort of thing that came up. And in Esperanto "drip" and "drop" use the same root. I figured it made sense because that's basically how an infusion limits the rate of administration, by literally giving it a drop at a time. Hence: gutado - dripping.

Comment: Ah, I fear that it might be Google translate artefact then. Sometimes one sees effects of English idioms or English homonyms even in Google translations from one non-English language to another non-English language. Thus I'd refrain from using that translation if it cannot be sourced by human-authored texts or dictionary entries.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate "intravenous infusion" as *envejna infuzo*.

The *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro* does not give a medical definition for *infuzi*, and seems to assign that meaning to *perfuzi* instead. The problem is that "infusion" and "perfusion" are not synonyms in English-language medical literature, as the latter uses an exterior pump as a replacement for normal circulation; but in French, "perfusion" is used for both.

Since Hradil's [*Esperanta Medicina Terminaro*](http://www.eventoj.hu/steb/vortaroj/medicina-vortaro-de-umea.pdf) does however make this distinction, I think it is okay to use *infuzo* for medical infusions.

Answer (score 0):

## From word roots, suffixes and prefixes:

#### verb

The action being done is inputting or injecting: *enmet-*

#### accusative noun

The thing being inputted is some sort of liquid: *ialikvaĵ-*

#### preposition

The liquid is being injected into the skin or body: *korpo* or *haŭto*

#### What it is

an act or process so the word will end in *-o*

## Result

*ialikvaĵenkorpmeto* = Process in which some kind of liquid is inserted into a body